# std_lib_facilities.h C++ error while compiling exercise

Tags: c++, macos

I'm trying to write a program for an exercise in the book *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++* by Bjarne Stroustrup the program is supposed to be a little game called Bulls and Cows where the user tries to guess a four digit number. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include "../Library/std_lib_facilities.h"

class string_error{};

/*
 * Method to determine if an integer is
 * in a vector
 */
bool contains(vector<int> v,int k ){

}

int string_to_int(string s){
    if(s == "0") return 0;
    else if(s == "1")return 1;
    else if(s == "2")return 2;
    else if(s == "3")return 3;
    else if(s == "4")return 4;
    else if(s == "5")return 5;
    else if(s == "6")return 6;
    else if(s == "7")return 7;
    else if(s == "8")return 8;
    else if(s == "9")return 9;
    else throw string_error();
}

int main(){

    /*
     * There is an int vector with the numbers
     * of the answer in it
     *
     * There is also an int vector with the numbers
     * of the user's guess
     *
     * User inputs a four digit integer that is read as
     * a string called str_guess
     *
     * for each digit in the guess string the digit is
     * converted to an integer and added to the guess vector
     *
     * The guess vector is then run through for each digit in the vector
     * each digit is checked against the answer at the same index
     * if the digit in the answer at that index number is not the same as the
     * digit in the guess vector then the digit is checked if the answer
     * vector contains it at all
     *
     * for each number that is correct for both the value and position
     * 1 is added to the bull value
     * for each number that is within the answer value but not in the correct position
     * 1 is added to the cow value
     *
     * The bull and cow values are displayed after the user enters their guess
     *
     * The user is prompted for a guess until their guess returns 4 bulls
     */

    vector<int> answer;
    answer.push_back(7);
    answer.push_back(9);
    answer.push_back(2);
    answer.push_back(4);

    string str_guess = "";
    cout << "Enter a four digit integer as a guess";
    cin >> str_guess;
    vector<int> guess;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        int guess_digit = string_to_int(str_guess[i]);
        guess.push_back(guess_digit);
    }
    cout << "Length of guess vector: " + guess.size();



}
```

As you can see I am using Mr.Stroustrup's header file std_lib_facilities.h([here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h)) unfortunately whenever I try to compile my program I get this error:

```
In file included from ../Bulls_and_Cows.cpp:13:
../../Library/std_lib_facilities.h:106:38: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >')
        template<class S> String(S s) :std::string(s) {}
```

I am on a mac using eclipse and the mac os gcc compiler. Any help you could provide me would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `string_to_int` receives a string and you pass a char

```
int guess_digit = string_to_int(str_guess[i]);
//                                       ^^^ access a position of the string that is a char
```

Comment: Another question for you, for some reason when I try to instantiate the vector answer (or any other vector) it returns an error when I try to use list format. E.g. vector<int> answer = {7,9,2,4} doesn't work. Do you have any guess as to why?

Comment: This is a C++11 syntax that constructs the object by initializer list. To use that you need to set the flag `-std=c++11` in compiling. E.g. `g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp`. If you are using an IDE, look the compiler settings.